# Azure SDK Python: tag a particular resource

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python

I want to create tag on each resource in Azure using python.

I see this module in the docs:
http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.operations.html#azure.mgmt.resource.resources.operations.TagsOperations

create_or_update: Create a subscription resource tag
list: Get a list of subscription resource tags

**Seems like I can only do tag operations on resource group and not resource?**

Example:

To add a tag to a resource group: Set-AzureRmResourceGroup
add tags to a resource: Set-AzureRmResource

EDIT:

Thanks for the api lookup code, very neat. But I believe the old api that I manually put should also work. I tried your code with little modification(we might have different Azure SDK, I am using 2.0.0rc5). After adding the api function(very helpful), I still have the same error unfortunately.

```
from azure.common.credentials import UserPassCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource.resources import ResourceManagementClient

def resolve_resource_api(client, resource):
    """ This method retrieves the latest non-preview api version for
    the given resource (unless the preview version is the only available
    api version) """
    provider = client.providers.get(resource.id.split('/')[6])
    rt = next((t for t in provider.resource_types
               if t.resource_type == '/'.join(resource.type.split('/')[1:])), None)
    #print(rt)
    if rt and 'api_versions' in rt.__dict__:
        #api_version = [v for v in rt[0].api_versions if 'preview' not in v.lower()]
        #return npv[0] if npv else rt[0].api_versions[0]
        api_version = [v for v in rt.__dict__['api_versions'] if 'preview' not in v.lower()]
        return api_version[0] if api_version else rt.__dict__['api_versions'][0]

credentials = UserPassCredentials(
    '****@****.com',    # Your new user
    '******',  # Your password
)

subscription_id= '*****-***-****-****-*******'

resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials,
                                                    subscription_id)

for resource in resource_client.resources.list():
    #print(resource)
    #print(resolve_resource_api(resource_client, resource))
    if resource.id.split('/')[4] == 'Build':
        #resource.tags = {'foo':'bar'}
        if resource.type == 'Microsoft.Web/sites':
            print('resource.id: ', resource.id)
            print('resource_group_name: ', resource.id.split('/')[4])
            print('resource_provider_namespace: ', resource.id.split('/')[6])
            print('parent_resource_path: ', '')
            print('resource_type: ', str(resource.type).split('/')[-1])
            print('resource_name: ', resource.name)
            print('api_version: ', resolve_resource_api(resource_client, resource))
            resource.tags['test'] = 'test1'

            #print(resolve_resource_api(resource_client, resource))
            #continue
            print(resource)
            resource_client.resources.create_or_update(
                resource_group_name= resource.id.split('/')[4], # Extract from resource.id
                resource_provider_namespace=resource.id.split('/')[6], # Extract from resource.id
                parent_resource_path='', # Extract from resource.id
                resource_type=str(resource.type).split('/')[-1], # Extract from resource type
                resource_name=resource.name,
                api_version=resolve_resource_api(resource_client, resource),
                parameters=resource
                )
        print('-'*10)
```

> Error
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python35-32\Scripts\Azure\temp.py", line 56, in 
>       parameters=resource
>     File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\azure\mgmt\resource\resources\operations\resources_operations.py", line 408, in create_or_update
>       raise exp
>   msrestazure.azure_exceptions.CloudError: Operation failed with status: 'Bad Request'. Details: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/***-***-***-*****-*******/resourcegroups/Build/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/build-dev?api-version=2016-03-01

I worked more and found the I am able to use the create_or_update method in the following way:

```
from azure.mgmt.resource.resources.models import GenericResource
parameters=GenericResource(
        location='West US',
        properties={},
    )
```

And the response error message with your code example says that "The parameter properties has an invalid value". So I am guessing parameters=resource needs to be fixed. I will look more into that.

UPDATE (SOLVED!):

```
for resource in resource_client.resources.list():
    #print(resource)
    if resource.id.split('/')[4] == 'Build':
        if resource.type == 'Microsoft.Web/sites':
            print('resource.id: ', resource.id)
            print('resource_group_name: ', resource.id.split('/')[4])
            print('resource_provider_namespace: ', resource.id.split('/')[6])
            print('parent_resource_path: ', '')
            print('resource_type: ', str(resource.type).split('/')[-1])
            print('resource_name: ', resource.name)
            print('api_version: ', resolve_resource_api(resource_client, resource))
            if not resource.tags:
                resource.tags = {}
                resource.tags['test'] = 'test1'
            else:
                resource.tags['test'] = 'test1'

            # This solves the error 400 Client Error: Bad Request. The parameter properties has an invalid value. 
            if not resource.properties:
                resource.properties = {}

            resource_client.resources.create_or_update(
                resource_group_name= resource.id.split('/')[4], # Extract from resource.id
                resource_provider_namespace=resource.id.split('/')[6], # Extract from resource.id
                parent_resource_path='', # Extract from resource.id
                resource_type=str(resource.type).split('/')[-1], # Extract from resource type
                resource_name=resource.name,
                api_version=resolve_resource_api(resource_client, resource),
                parameters=resource,
                )
        print('-'*10)
```

**For some odd reason, if the resource.properties is None, the requests does not like it. It has to be {}.**

Thank you for your help Travis! I will post more questions as I work on Azure SDK ;)

Comment: update the link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resource/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2020_06_01.operations.tagsoperations?view=azure-python#azure-mgmt-resource-resources-v2020-06-01-operations-tagsoperations-create-or-update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the Python SDK, you can generally add tags to a resource using that resource's `create_or_update` method. These methods take an object called `parameters` which is generally the object type of the resource you are interested in. This is where you will find tags.

For example to tag a virtual network:

```
from azure.mgmt.network.models import VirtualNetwork

vnet = client.virtual_networks.get(resource_group_name, vnet_name)
vnet.tags = {'a':'b'}
client.virtual_networks.create_or_update(resource_group_name, virtual_network_name, vnet)
```

Additionally, you can tag your resource through Xplat-Cli using (for this example) the `azure network vnet set -t {tags}` command.

You can tag resource groups using `azure group set -t {tags}` and resources generically using `azure resource set -t {tags}`.

Hopefully that helps.

**UPDATE (8/26/16)**

Getting API versions can be tricky. You would think it would just be part of the generic resource object, but for some reason it's not. However, try something like this:

```
from azure.common.credentials import UserPassCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource.resources import ResourceManagementClient

def resolve_resource_api(client, resource):
    """ This method retrieves the latest non-preview api version for
    the given resource (unless the preview version is the only available
    api version) """
    provider = client.providers.get(resource.id.split('/')[6])
    rt = next((t for t in provider.resource_types if t.resource_type == resource.type), None)
    if rt and len(rt) == 1 and rt[0].api_versions:
        api_version = [v for v in rt[0].api_versions if 'preview' not in v.lower()]
        return npv[0] if npv else rt[0].api_versions[0]

credentials = UserPassCredentials(
    '****@****.com',    # Your new user
    '******',  # Your password
)

subscription_id= '*****-***-****-****-*******'

resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

for resource in resource_client.resources.list():
    resource.tags['test'] = 'test1'

    # avoid error 400 if properties must be set
    if not resource.properties:
        resource.properties = {}

    resource_client.resources.create_or_update(
        resource_group_name= resource.id.split('/')[4],
        resource_provider_namespace=resource.id.split('/')[6],
        parent_resource_path='', # WARNING: this will not work with child resources
        resource_type=str(resource.type).split('/')[-1],
        resource_name=resource.name,
        api_version=resolve_resource_api(resource_client, resource),
        parameters=resource
    )
```

The list operation under client.resources gives a paged list of GenericResource objects for the entire subscription. The way you posted, you looped through the resource groups one by one and then through the resources within each resource group. That will work just fine, and it will avoid you having to extract the resource group name from the ID, but I think this solution is a little cleaner.

The `resolve_resource_api` method uses the provider namespace and the resource type from the resource ID to look up the available API versions for that resource type using the resource provider get operation. This code (which is missing some validation) will retrieve the most recent API versions that is not a preview version (unless that is the only version available). Just arbitrarily specifying a version in a string is not going to work generally, as the different resources will have different API versions.

Also, your code specifies '' for parent path, so this would not work generally for a child resource.

Comment: Hi Travis, thanks for the guidance. I want to iterate through every resource and add a tag, and I found create_or_update method of azure.mgmt.resource.resources.operations.ResourcesOperations to be useful. However I am not able to follow the document. I have updated my original post with a sample code.

Comment: Hi Travis, sorry about the late reply. I am still where I was. I used the get method instead of create_or_update as an initial check if my parameters are correct. I am not able to find enough information about parent_resource_path and api_version. I tried a code with check_existence method and I get False for every iteration. Maybe using Azure CLI with Bash would be an easier option for me.

Comment: WIth the previous code with get method I got these errors: msrestazure.azure_exceptions.CloudError: The resource type could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.ClassicCompute' for api version '2016-02-01'.

msrestazure.azure_exceptions.CloudError: The resource type could not be found in the namespace 'microsoft.insights' for api version '2016-02-01'.

Comment: Travis, I did more studying and have figured out the solution. Thanks for your help. I will update the post with my solution soon. The resource type is actually str(resource.type).split('/')[-1], instead of resource.type.

Comment: HI Travis, I got excited seeing all the information when the get method was working for me. BUt I am not able to get create_or_update method to work now. I think I am very close. Can you please help? I have updated the code. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Travis, thanks for the api function, but my code remains unchanged and I still see the error. For the resource site, I do not have a parent_resource_path '', so the parameters seems to be correct for this case, as I put the condition resource.type == 'Microsoft.Web/sites' as an initial script .

Comment: What was missing?

Comment: # This solves the error 400 Client Error: Bad Request. The parameter properties has an invalid value. 
            if not resource.properties:
                resource.properties = {}

Comment: This error is caused in sites resources, for some reason resource.properties cannot be None.

Comment: Great to hear you got it working! I've updated my answer to include setting the properties as you mentioned. If you feel my answer would be useful for someone looking to generically tag all resources in their subscription, please accept my answer. :)

Comment: @TravisPrescott How can I create a new tag using the above method ?