# Azure Python SDK Tagging Resources in Resource group

Tags: python, azure-runbook

I am using azure python runbook to Tag all resources in specific resource group. I am not able to find proper help/documentation how to update all resources in that  resource group.

```
resource_group_params = {'location': 'westeurope'}

# Modify the Resource group
resource_group_params.update(tags={'hello': 'world', 'new': 'tag'})
print_item(client.resources.create_or_update(GROUP_NAME, resource_id, resource_group_params))
```

its complaining that resources.create_or_update takes at least 8 parameters only 4 provided

Can any one share me example or explain what are the parameters required to update/tag resources 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992201/azure-sdk-python-tag-a-particular-resource) for the details.

As well, you can also check the source code of `create_or_update` method following below steps(I used the `visual studio code` for the editor):

1.Select the method, then Press F12 button.

[image]

2.In the method definition, you can see the explanation for the parameters.

[image]

Comment: Thanks man for help it worked, but this is really bad way to understand some SDK i am new to Azure and seems like several stuff Azure didn't documented properly

Comment: I also have one question regarding the Link you shared. I get error API version cannot be NONE

Comment: @OwaisAhmad, where you get this error? in the create_or_update() method?

Comment: Yes in create_or_update method, The is code i copied from link you shared. There is some function to get api version its returning None

Comment: Hi @OwaisAhmad, could you please open a new thread about this issue, and then put the address here? Thanks.