# Azure tags update 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'

Tags: python, azure, azure-runbook

Hi i am updating resources tags in azure with python and runbook. I am able to update tags on most of resources but some of resources are giving me this error

**'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'**

i am using code spinet as also mentioned in [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992201/azure-sdk-python-tag-a-particular-resource)

```
resource.tags.update(tag_dic)
if not resource.properties: 
    resource.properties = {}

resource_client.resources.create_or_update(                                   
resource_group_name=resource.id.split('/')[4],                       
resource_provider_namespace=resource.id.split('/')[6],
parent_resource_path='',
resource_type="",
resource_name=resource.name,
api_version=2018-M-D, 
parameters=resource
)
```

Comment: For example this disk resource /subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/CPS_PX/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/px-xx gives me this error

This could be possibility that this child resource of vm resource?

Answer (score 0):

Likely the code is telling you that `resource.tags` is sometimes `None`. You might want to try before the code you mention:

```
if not resource.tags:
    resource.tags = {}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply i tried but it says 

        Azure Error: InvalidParameter
        Message: Required parameter 'creationData' is missing (null).
        Target: creationData

Comment: So, when you use create_or_update, you need to be sure `resource` is coming from a GET before. Otherwise you might update more than you expect, because the RestAPI will do a diff of what you send and what was sent the last time. If you are missing some part (creationData), it will fail

Comment: You can also use the simple `update` that will do a HTTP PATCH, but not all service supports it.

Comment: I suggest you open an issue for each particular resource_type here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues

Comment: That`s very good to know that working at MS should be very amazing experience.

Answer (score 0):

For disk resource they are cannot be accessed from resource.client call because disks are child resource of VM not of resources group. For disks we need to call compute.client

```
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(
    azure_credential,
    subscription_id,
    base_url=resourceManager_url)
managed_disk = compute_client.disks.get(resource_group, disk_name)
managed_disk.tags = {"test_tag":"yes"}
try:
    compute_client.disks.create_or_update(
        resource_group,
        resource_name_curr,
        managed_disk
    )
```